# Unable to connect to linux GCP instance through SSH

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform

I have a scenario,
We have created a linux instance(Ubuntu 16.04) in Google Cloud Platform.
I was connecting to instance created by our lead, through SSH from the gcp console. But now I am not able to connect through SSH.
 I have tried to generate private and public key through putty. I tried connecting with the keys through Putty, i get following error:
Authentication not supported(public key). Putty is refusing my key.
I have added the public key in the project Metadata.

Comment: This question is more suited to Serverfault where it should be asked. Stackoverflow is generally for developers and Serverfault is aimed at system and network administrators).

Answer (score 1):

After adding your public key in the project Metadata, do you try to connect specifying your private key? The next command works for me from a Linux terminal:

```
ssh -i [PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY] [USERNAME]@[EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS]
```

Comment: i am trying to connect by putty using private key, i am not able to do it.

Comment: Have you already checked this website: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced? It explains how to connect through putty. It works for me